# Explicit locks in RedShift

Tags: locking, redshift

I'm new to AWS Redshift and I wanted to know How i can implement my use-case.

I have a Redshift table which gets lot of Inserts/Selects.
In some cases I need to delete some data from that table. I don't want my Delete to impact other writes and reads.

Can someone suggest what is the best locking mode available in Redshift to implement my use case.

I don't want to end up with dadlocks and some locks hanging in my application.

I tried without locks and I'm observing the following violation:

```
Serializable isolation violation on table - 156300, transactions forming the cycle are: 6416378, 6416913 (pid:3770);
```

Also I went through the Redshift cxplicit locks but couldn't find any Official documentation for the same.

I know that Redshift is a wrapper on PostgreSQL, so can I use that documentation for implementing?

Comment: Redshift is not a "wrapper" for Postgres. It's a _fork_ of a very, very old version of Postgres (and a completely different product in the meantime)

Comment: So can i use postgresql documentation about explicit locking which I Couldn't find in RedShift documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it works like PostgreSQL in this case:

This is a serialization error that you get because you are using the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level.

That is nothing to worry about, just repeat the transaction.

Comment: Can you suggest any Locking mode ? Which doesn't impact my INSERT/SELECT's in one transaction(T1) while I'm deleting data in another transaction (T2)

Comment: There shouldn't be any conflicts, unless maybe the file is empty or locks are escalating. Does the error happen every time?

Comment: as of now we are not using any locks on the table and when mulitple writes (Deletes,Inserts) are happening in parallel we are seeing this error

Answer (score -2):

In order to avoid the above mentioned error, you can use the LOCK  command to explicitly lock in that transaction.

Comment: Which explicit locks? Please provide an example.